# Application Client using remote interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Please see the code below:

```
//Main.Java
    package clienttest;

    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import test.TestEJBRemote;

    /**
     *
     * @author 
     */
    public class Main {
        @EJB
        private static TestEJBRemote testEJB;

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(testEJB.getName("Ian"));
        }

    }

    //TestEJBRemote.java
    package test;

    import javax.ejb.Remote;

    /**
     *
     * @author 
     */
    @Remote
    public interface TestEJBRemote {
        public String getName (String name);
    }

//TestEJB
package test;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Stateless
public class TestEJB implements TestEJBRemote {

    @Override
    public String getName(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
}
```

Q1) Does this mean I can deploy Main.java to another PC on the network and run it?
Q2) Once deployed, then how does Main.java know where to look for testEJB?

Answer (score 0):

The details are vendor-specific, but the application client typically has a command-line option to specify the target server host and port.